# Evenly distributed flow in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to simulate a "physical" flow by using a graph. A simple source/supply node 0 and two sink/demand nodes {3,4}. Two is a distribution node. I was expecting that flow is distributed evenly to the sink nodes once the source does not supply sufficient flow. But it doesn't.
Here the example (simplification from what I am up to):

```
tg = Graph[{0 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, 
  EdgeCapacity -> {0 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 1.5, 
    1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> 1}]
oftg = FindMaximumFlow[tg, 0, {2, 3}, "OptimumFlowData"];
TableForm[oftg["FlowMatrix"], 
 TableHeadings -> {VertexList[tg], VertexList[tg]}]
```

The flow matrix shows that node 3 gets flow 1, node 2 gets flow 0.5. Instead of each getting 0.75.

Is there a setting to get an even distribution of the flow to the two demand/sink nodes?
If not possible what would be an alternative to simulate flow from several source to several sinks with inbetween points?

Btw. I tried to set a minimum/maximum flow that works not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

There does not appear to be an option to specify how "optimum" is defined. Presumably, the definition used maximizes the maximum flow to the sink nodes. If you want to maximize the balanced flow, average the flows for graphs `{0\[DirectedEdge]1, 1\[DirectedEdge]2, 1\[DirectedEdge]3}` and `{0\[DirectedEdge]1, 1\[DirectedEdge]3, 1\[DirectedEdge]2}`

```
{tg, tg2} = Graph[#,
     EdgeCapacity ->
      {0 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 3/2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 1, 
       1 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> 1}] & /@
   {{0 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
     1 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, {0 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
     1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}};

{oftg, oftg2} = FindMaximumFlow[#, 0, {2, 3},
     "OptimumFlowData"] & /@ {tg, tg2};

TableForm[
 (oftg["FlowMatrix"] + 
    Transpose[Transpose[oftg2["FlowMatrix"]][[{1, 2, 4, 3}]]])/2,
 TableHeadings -> {VertexList[tg], VertexList[tg]}]
```

[image]

However, for more complicated graphs this will require additional coding.

**EDIT:** Another example,

```
Graph[{0 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  1 \[DirectedEdge] 4},
 EdgeCapacity -> {0 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 1.5},
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Varying the order of edges `{1\[DirectedEdge]2, 1\[DirectedEdge]3, 1\[DirectedEdge]4}` for the graph definition

```
edgeLists = Join[{0 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, #] & /@
   Permutations[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
     1 \[DirectedEdge] 4}];

nmax = Length@edgeLists;
```

The graphs are

```
(tg[#] = Graph[edgeLists[[#]],
      EdgeCapacity -> {0 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> 1.5}]) & /@
  Range[nmax];
```

Note that the [`EdgeCapacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeCapacity.html) defaults to`1` if not specified.

The [`OptimumFlowData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptimumFlowData.html) objects are

```
(oftg[#] = FindMaximumFlow[tg[#], 0, {2, 3, 4}, "OptimumFlowData"]) & /@ 
  Range[nmax];
```

Taking the [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) of the flow matrices,

```
TableForm[
 Mean[
  Table[
   #[[VertexList[tg[n]] + 1]] & /@ Normal[oftg[n]["FlowMatrix"]],
   {n, nmax}]],
 TableHeadings ->
  {VertexList[tg[1]], VertexList[tg[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: My graph that I want to work with is way more complicated. It contains two sources and 6 sinks. So it needs soneother than graphs approach, I guess. However, your answer solves the problem as given.

Comment: A graph with 2 sources and 6 sinks doesn't sound excessively large (unless there are a large number of intermediate vertices). Perhaps you can post a new question with the full graph definition.

Comment: In total the full graph has 27 verticies. I have to re-think a better approach.